# Identifying table cells in a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I am trying to implement [FlatUIKit](https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit) in a custom cell in a UITableView within my ViewController that returns values to NSUserDefaults based on the switch state. As a usual switch, I have method 'saveSwitchState' connected to the valueChanged outlet. The problem is in I want to pass the state to the user defaults and use the label as the key, but the method can't access the the cells and labels. I have tried adding:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
setupOneCell *cell = (setupOneCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to the method, but still no luck. If there is a better way to save the switch states that with a valueChanged method I'm all ears. Below is my ViewController and Custom Cell.

ViewController.m:

```
#import "setup1ViewController.h"
#import "setup1TableView.h"
#import "setupOneCell.h"
#import "Social.h"
#import "FUISwitch.h"
#import "UIFont+FlatUI.h"
#import "UIColor+FlatUI.h"

@interface setup1ViewController ()

- (IBAction)saveSwitchState:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation setup1ViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.oneTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.oneTableView.delegate = self;

    self.medias = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Social *media = [[Social alloc] init];
    media.socialMedia = @"Facebook";
    [self.medias addObject:media];

    media = [[Social alloc] init];
    media.socialMedia = @"Twitter";
    [self.medias addObject:media];

    media = [[Social alloc] init];
    media.socialMedia = @"Instagram";
    [self.medias addObject:media];

    media = [[Social alloc] init];
    media.socialMedia = @"Tumblr";
    [self.medias addObject:media];

    media = [[Social alloc] init];
    media.socialMedia = @"Gmail";
    [self.medias addObject:media];

    media = [[Social alloc] init];
    media.socialMedia = @"Linked In";
    [self.medias addObject:media];

    media = [[Social alloc] init];
    media.socialMedia = @"GitHub";
    [self.medias addObject:media];

    media = [[Social alloc] init];
    media.socialMedia = @"You Tube";
    [self.medias addObject:media];

    media = [[Social alloc] init];
    media.socialMedia = @"Vine";
    [self.medias addObject:media];

    media = [[Social alloc] init];
    media.socialMedia = @"SoundCloud";
    [self.medias addObject:media];


    //self.setup1Table.editing = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.medias count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    setupOneCell *cell = (setupOneCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.cellSwitch.onColor = [UIColor turquoiseColor];
    cell.cellSwitch.offColor = [UIColor cloudsColor];
    cell.cellSwitch.onBackgroundColor = [UIColor midnightBlueColor];
    cell.cellSwitch.offBackgroundColor = [UIColor silverColor];
    cell.cellSwitch.offLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:14];
    cell.cellSwitch.onLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:14];

    Social *media = (self.medias)[indexPath.row];

    cell.socialName.text = media.socialMedia;


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return;
}

- (IBAction)saveSwitchState:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([cell.cellSwitch isOn])
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:cellLabel];
    else
        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:cellLabel];
}

@end
```

setupOneCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FUISwitch.h"
#import "UIFont+FlatUI.h"
#import "UIColor+FlatUI.h"

@interface setupOneCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *socialName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FUISwitch *cellSwitch;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to have your cell listen for the switch value changing, then report that change to your view controller through a delegate call.  Then in your view controller you can look up what data is associated with that cell and use that to modify `NSUserDefaults`.

How to do this:

Inside your cell's setup code you should add the cell as a target for the switch, instead of having your view controller be the target.  (Probably in your cell's `-awakeFromNib` but it could also work in some sort of `-configureWithSocialMedia:` method.)

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self.cellSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)switchValueChanged:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate setupOneCell:self witchValueDidChange:[self.cellSwitch isOn]];
}
```

Then create a protocol with a method like `-setupOneCell:switchValueDidChange:` that passes your cell and the switch value.  Make your cell take a delegate that follows this protocol.

Code would be like this for the protocol:

```
@protocol SetupOneCellDelegate;

@interface setupOneCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *socialName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FUISwitch *cellSwitch;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SetupOneCellDelegate> delegate;

@end


@protocol SetupOneCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)setupOneCell:(setupOneCell *)cell switchValueDidChange:(BOOL)switchValue;

@end
```

Now your view controller is all set to get a callback from the cell when its switch value changes.  When you configure your cell, make sure to set the view controller as the delegate:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    setupOneCell *cell = (setupOneCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.cellSwitch.onColor = [UIColor turquoiseColor];
    cell.cellSwitch.offColor = [UIColor cloudsColor];
    cell.cellSwitch.onBackgroundColor = [UIColor midnightBlueColor];
    cell.cellSwitch.offBackgroundColor = [UIColor silverColor];
    cell.cellSwitch.offLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:14];
    cell.cellSwitch.onLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:14];

    Social *media = (self.medias)[indexPath.row];

    cell.socialName.text = media.socialMedia;

    cell.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

And finally implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)setupOneCell:(setupOneCell *)cell switchValueDidChange:(BOOL)switchValue {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.oneTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSString *label = [self.medias[indexPath.row] socialMedia];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:switchValue forKey:label];
}
```